# Change value in parentViewController when back button in childViewController was pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need something like this 
`self.parentViewController.someValue = 20`. Is it possible? I use UINavigationBar. And I want when user tapped on back button, some value in my main controller changed.

Comment: What is a parent view controller?

Comment: In order for us to be able to answer your question, you need to add some more information. Right now there isn't enough detail included for anyone to do much more than guess :) From what you have, the complete answer is "Yes".

Comment: Maybe I something wrote wrong. I use UINavigationBar. And I want when user tapped on back button, some in my main controller changed.

Comment: may be will better use viewWillAppear in this case?

Comment: @aknew no, viewWillAppear need for me to another purpose.. I need to change value only when back button was tapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of four ways to do this and there are probably more that aren't coming to mind.

1) Update a data model and have the parent controller be an observer of the change using KVO.

2) Send a notification when the second controller is going away and have the parent listen for it.

3) Create a delegate protocol that lets the second controller reference a parent method directly.

4) Use the parent's `viewWillAppear:` and check the `isMovingToParentViewController` property for whether it's just re-appearing.

You have lots of choices!  :)